# Email to group using EWS C#

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using ExchangeWebServices C#.
I'm trying to send an email to distributio list, so 
I'm created a group as follow:

```
private void CreateGroup(ExchangeService service)
{
    // Create a new contact group object.
    ContactGroup myContactGroup = new ContactGroup(service);

    // Give the group a name.
    myContactGroup.DisplayName = "TestContactGroup";

    // Add some members to the group.
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("Euser@mydomain.com"));
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("Euser1@mydomain.com"));
    myContactGroup.Members.Add(new GroupMember("Euser2@mydomain.com"));

    // Save the group.
    myContactGroup.Save();

}
```

Now I'm trying to send email to this group, how can i do that?
What i'm tried:

```
EmailMessage email = new EmailMessage(service);
email.ToRecipients.Add("TestContactGroup");//Throw an exception "At least one recipient isn't valid."
//email.ToRecipients.Add("TestContactGroup@mydomain.com");//"Return" the mail that "The email address you entered couldn't be found."

email.Subject = "MySubject";
email.Body = new MessageBody("MyBody");

// Send the mail
email.Send();
```

If I'm trying to send to `TestContactGroup` i'm got an exception:

> "At least one recipient isn't valid."

And if I'm trying to send to `TestContactGroup@mydomain.com` I'm got an email that the mail isn't found.

So, how can i send an email to group list that I'm crated? Or another way to create distribution list with EWS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.
I'm just need to add the group id as follow:

```
myContactGroup.Id = grpId;
```

I'm get my group id as follow:

```
// Instantiate the item view with the number of items to retrieve from the Contacts folder.
        ItemView view = new ItemView(9999);

         // Request the items in the Contacts folder that have the properties that you selected.
        FindItemsResults<Item> contactItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Contacts, view);
        string groupId = string.Empty;
        List<ItemId> groupItemIds = new List<ItemId>();

        // Loop through all contacts 
        foreach (Item item in contactItems)
        {
            //Check to see if ContactGroup
            if (item is ContactGroup)
            {
                //Get the contact group
                ContactGroup contactGroup = item as ContactGroup;
                groupItemIds.Add(item.Id);//Using to send an email by item id, can classify by DisplayName etc..
            }
        }
```